# Python Numeric Formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a simple program to calculate some steam properties

```
import numpy as np

from iapws import IAPWS97

sat_steam=IAPWS97(P=0.1,T=373.15)                   
sat_liquid=IAPWS97(T=100+273.15, x=0)               
steam=IAPWS97(P=2.5, T=500)                     


print(sat_steam.s, sat_liquid.P, steam.h) #calculated properties
```

How do I output the numbers such that only a single decimal place is showing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `round()` function from the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#round

```
import numpy as np

from iapws import IAPWS97

sat_steam=round(IAPWS97(P=0.1,T=373.15), 1)                   
sat_liquid=round(IAPWS97(T=100+273.15, x=0), 1)               
steam=round(IAPWS97(P=2.5, T=500), 1)                     


print(sat_steam.s, sat_liquid.P, steam.h) #calculated properties
```